# CVXOPT GLPK returns wrong solution

Tags: python, linear-programming, convex-optimization

I'm using python interface to GLPK. 
I'm looking for a solution X that:

- Minimizes c
- G * X <= H
- A * X = b

I'm using the following statement

```
glpk.ilp(c,G,h,A,b,I=set(range(25)))
```

Tha'ts my G matrix:

```
-1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  -1  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0  0   0  0
```

That's my h matrix

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.001
```

That's my A matrix

```
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

That's my B matrix

```
21.0 21.0 21.0 21.0  21.0 21.0 21.0 21.0 21.0 21.0  21.0 21.0 21.0 21.0 21.0  21.0  21.0  21.0  21.0  21.0
```

Yet by executing the following:

```
sol=glpk.ilp(c,G,h,A,b,I=set(range(25)))
```

I get the following solution:

```
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
```

Which is clearly wrong.

Since 
    A * X != b

I don't have any lead to how to troubleshoot this. The documentation is scarce.

Comment: question looks too specific please explain some more code.

Comment: It is very specific. I'll edit

Comment: Why is it clearly wrong? What are you expecting to get? Can you give a link to the software you are using, and to a Wikipedia (or similar) page on the mathematical operation you are trying to do?

Comment: what are the sizes of the A and of the B matrices ?

Comment: I've edited. 
The code that constructs the actual matrices is complex and won't help a lot. 
@Blair - I'm trying to do convex optimization [link to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization)

Answer (score 0):

dI copied your arrays to text files (names should be self-explanatory) and ran the following code without problems.

Perhaps converting your arrays to proper cvxopt matrizes was the problem?

```
import numpy as np
import cvxopt
import cvxopt.glpk

c=cvxopt.matrix(np.loadtxt('c.txt'),tc='d')
A=cvxopt.matrix(np.loadtxt('A.txt'),tc='d')
b=cvxopt.matrix(np.loadtxt('b.txt'),tc='d')
G=cvxopt.matrix(np.loadtxt('G.txt'),tc='d')
h=cvxopt.matrix(np.loadtxt('h.txt'),tc='d')

sol=cvxopt.glpk.ilp(c,G,h,A,b,I=set(range(25)))

x=[i for i in sol[1]]
# x=[0 0 10 0 0 10 0 10 10 10 0 0 0 10 10 10 10 0 10 10 0 0 1 1 1]

eq=(np.dot(A,x)==b.T[0]).all()
# eq=True
```

Thus, the solution vector x is different from the one you reported.

In particular, the last line checks for equality A*x=b and evaluates to true.

Hope that helps!